# How to find all possible pairwise combinations of binary vectors where second vector conditionally depend on the first vector?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, conditional-probability, permutation-matrices

I want to find all the possible pairwise combination where the 1 in 2nd vector is conditioned upon where 1 is located in the first vector of the pair. If in the first vector, there is a 1 in the 2nd position, then in the second vector, 1 can be either in 2nd or 3rd position but NOT IN first.

An acceptable output for two binary vectors of length 3 each. All vectors consists of a single 1 and rest are 0:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]    1    0    0
  [2,]    0    1    0  

  [1,]    1    0    0
  [2,]    0    0    1

  [1,]    0    1    0
  [2,]    0    0    1

  [1,]    1    0    0
  [2,]    1    0    0

  [1,]    0    1    0
  [2,]    0    1    0

  [1,]    0    0    1
  [2,]    0    0    1
```

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: Is the condition: the “1” in the second vector is either in the same place, or to the right of, the “1” in the first vector?

Comment: @Mike Earnest yes, that's the condition. It goes on in general case if we increase the number of vectors.

Comment: Since I have misinterpreted the query, I will delete my answer.  Questions: (1) Can a vector have a binary digit of $1$ in **more** than one position?  That is, does your query need to consider a vector like $(0,1,1)$.  Alternatively, does each vector only have the binary digit $1$ in **exactly** one slot? (2) Does your query need to consider that instead of having only two vectors, you may (in the general case) have $n$ vectors? ...see next comment

Comment: (3) Does your query need to consider that instead of each vector having a length of $3$ (i.e. having 3 slots), in the general case, each vector can have a length of $k$ (i.e. $k$ slots)? (4) Assuming that the answer to Q(1) is the latter, is the condition that each vector's positioning of its binary digit $1$ must not precede the corresponding positioning of any previous vector in the list? ...see next comment

Comment: On a personal note, consider the 4 questions that I am asking, and ask yourself whether your query very clearly already answered all 4 of the questions.  How was someone supposed to *answer* your query without your query **very clearly** anticipating and answering all of these questions?

Comment: @user2661923, 1) No, only one position of each vector can have 1, rest should be 0. (0,1,1) is not valid. 2 and 3) yes n and k should take any integer value. Example is only for illustration, expecting a more general answer. 4) Assume ith vector has 1 in position j. then (i+1)th vector can have 1 either on j or > j. I hope this clarifies your questions.

Comment: "I want to find all the possible pairwise combination" the only thing left to clarify is what you are asking.  What you have specified is that the vectors must be in "non-decreasing order".  Since a vector is allowed to *repeat*, it's hard to think of anything else to say.

Comment: @user2661923 Now I see your confusion. My question is not general. Should have worded them differently. In the question I asked only for pairwise combination but should have asked for combination of n vectors where each vector has a length of k.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking.  Please clarify more re what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any valid list of $n$ vectors, each with length $k$, can be represented by a list of $k$ nonnegative integers whose sum is $n$. Each entry in the list represents the number of ones in its corresponding column. For example,

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]    1    0    0       --->      (1, 1, 0)
  [2,]    0    1    0  

  [1,]    0    0    1       --->      (0, 0, 2)
  [2,]    0    0    1
```

So, you just need to list all vectors of length $k$ summing to $n$. You can easily doing this recursively, by making all possible choices for the first entry, then recursively filling the rest. After the following pseudo code is, the collection `allVectors` will contain all possible vectors.

```
set L to a list of length k (indexed from 1 to k)
set allVectors to an empty collection

procedure listAllVectors(sumOfRemainingEntries, currentIndex):
    if currentIndex = k:
        set L[currentIndex] to sumOfRemainingEntries
        add L to allVectors
    else:
        for i in {0, 1, ... , n}:
            set L[currentIndex] to i
            do listAllVectors(sumOfEntries - i, currentIndex + 1)

do listAllVectors(n, 1)
```